# Laravel - passing array of associative arrays to a partial

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass an associative array containing an array of associative arrays to the a partial in laravel 5.2:

```
        @include('admin.partials.context-menu', [
            'items' => [
               ['test' => 'test']
            ],
            'icon'  => 'more_vert'
        ])
```

and trying to access the array items inside the array:

```
<ul class="context-menu">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <li class="context-menu-item">
            {{ $item['test']  }}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

However, I get an error illegal string offset 'test', as I try to do it.

Things that I have tried so far:
Using indexed array 'items' - works, but very unintuitive to develop with
Passing object instead of associative array - unexpected behaviour, says it is an object when typeOf, but when accessing a value, says it is not an object.

I can var_dump things in the partial and all the values are as expected, but the problem only arises when I try to access their values via blade
as in

```
{{ $item['test']  }}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Is this all the code. e.g. does the key `test` exist on each `$item` ?

Answer (score 0):

All I can think is that you're missing the key on one of the items.

For example I can trigger the same error with the following code.

```
<?php

$array = [
    'items' => [
        ['test' => 'test'],
        ['key' => 'test2']
    ]
];

foreach ($array['items'] as $item) {
    var_dump($item['test']);
}
```

Try doing

```
@foreach ($items as $key => $value) // yes this works in blade
    {{ $item[$key] }}
@endforeach
```